# Update Custom Filter Values - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

So im trying to implement a multilanguage support for a webpage. Holding a JSON in a Controller and displaying these values worked fine and if i changed the JSON to another language it also updated like it should.

But I thought it might be better to realize it in another way, so Strings inside a directive does also get translated. So I wrote a custom filter, which should do the job.

At the moment I have a languageFactory, which provides the JSON via $http. The filter accesses the json. The problem at this point is, that it does not translate the expression with the filter again, after the JSON is loaded. If I change the value manually, the filter translates it again. Is there somehow a way to translate all expressions where the filter is used? $apply does not work, since the expression values did not change

Since I'm also started with Angular only 6 Weeks ago, i'm not sure if this solution is a good one. I'd also like to hear other possibilities to implement this.

---

// LanguageFactory

```
    lang.changeLanguage = function(language) {
        $http.get("assets/lang/" + language + ".json").success( function(json) {
            lang.all = json;
            lang.promise.resolve();
        });
    };
```

// TranslateFilter

```
       return function(item) {
            var lang = null;

            if(LanguageFactory.all === null) {
                LanguageFactory.getPromise().promise.then(function() {
                    lang = LanguageFactory.all;
                }); 
            }
            else {
                lang = LanguageFactory.all;
            }

            if(lang !== null) {
                return lang[item];   // <- RETURN here translation
            }
            else {
                return "";
            }          
        };
```

// index.html

```
<span id="test1">{{iCtrl.something | translate}}</span>
```

My problem is that the filter will not be reapplied, if the value of the expression does not change, but I want that it will be reapplied even if nothing changed on those expressions.

Comment: Show your code implementation approach. Not clear what your problem is specifically. A demo would also help. Note that there are some well developed translation modules available

Comment: `filter` needs to be synchronous

Comment: I know that I get returned nothing at first, since my filter uses an async call. But if it gets reapplied, the filter does the job it should. I'm just looking for a way to reapply it everywhere.

Comment: $stateful does the trick, but its discouraged since it'll impact the preformance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this: http://jsfiddle.net/TahmidTanzim/N9Vqk/

But your question, use the filter as:

```
angular.module('App.filters', []).filter('companyFilter', [function () {
    return function (clients, selectedCompany) {
      /* Here implement your filter custom by language. Look example in link jsfiddle */
    };
}]);
```

In html:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="client in filtered = (clients | companyFilter:<language selected>)">
```

Comment: Since I use $http the JSON is loaded async. This means the filter cant return a translation immediately. Thats why I have a promise, which will be fullfilled when JSON is available. This also works to this point. The only problem is, that I want to update now all expression. Since my expression does not change, the filter will not be reapplied. But if I change my expression to something random and than back again to my expression, it will get translated correctly since a change happend to the expression. But I want to force that all expression mit the filter will be reapplied,

Comment: When populate the variable with language, after resolve promise the filter is executable.

Comment: and how exactly do i execute it again?

Comment: The angular execute it again. This is automatic. Always after the model is update angular executable filter

Comment: At the moment im using my fitler with a Parameter and after loading a new language json i'll change the parameter and it updates. So in the end, your answer helped me there. 
Still im not satisfied with how it works at the moment. :/